# NuGet: Package was restored using .NET Framework instead of net5.0

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I am new to both .NET core and NuGet releasing.

- I built a .NET Core 5.0 class library.
- I built a .NET Core 5.0 console app to test this class library
- If the test console app directly reference the DLL built from this class library, everything works fine.
- If I build a NuGet package using the class library and release it, then download that package to the test console app, I get this warning:

"Package SkyBridge.ClientAPI.NetCore 1.0.0.3 was restored using
.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1,
.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2,
.NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1,
.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
.NETFramework,Version=v4.8
instead of the project target framework net5.0.
This package may not be fully compatible with your project."

This is the nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>SkyBridge.ClientAPI.NetCore</id>
    <version>1.0.0.3</version>
    <title>SkyBridge.ClientAPI (.NET Core)</title>
    <authors>Front Edge Software, Frank Lieu</authors>
    <owners>Front Edge Software, Frank Lieu</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>true</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <license type="file">SkyBridge_Client_API_Software_License_Agreement.txt</license>
    <licenseUrl>https://aka.ms/deprecateLicenseUrl</licenseUrl>
    <description>A class library used to act as a SkyBridge client and communicate with another SkyBridge client.</description>
    <summary>A class library used to act as a SkyBridge client and communicate with another SkyBridge client.</summary>
    <releaseNotes>Initial release.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright ©2021 Front Edge Software</copyright>
    <tags>Front Edge SkyBridge Client API Remoting</tags>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency id="Crc32.NET" version="1.2.0" />
        <dependency id="BouncyCastle.NetCore" version="1.8.10" />
        <dependency id="BouncyCastle.NetCoreSdk" version="1.9.3.1" />
        <dependency id="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" version="6.0.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="SkyBridge_Client_API_Software_License_Agreement.txt" target="" />
  </files>
</package>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I currently have a similar issue with net6.0, have you found a solution in your case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following nuspec solved the problem - I specified the .NET dependency:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>SkyBridgeAPI.NetCore</id>
    <version>1.0.0.6</version>
    <title>SkyBridgeAPI (.NET Core)</title>
    <authors>Front Edge Software, Frank Lieu</authors>
    <owners>Front Edge Software, Frank Lieu</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>true</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <license type="file">SkyBridgeAPI_Software_License_Agreement.txt</license>
    <licenseUrl>https://aka.ms/deprecateLicenseUrl</licenseUrl>
    <description>A class library used to act as a SkyBridge client and communicate with another SkyBridge client.</description>
    <summary>A class library used to act as a SkyBridge client and communicate with another SkyBridge client.</summary>
    <releaseNotes>Initial release.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright ©2021 Front Edge Software</copyright>
    <tags>Front Edge SkyBridge API Remoting</tags>
        
    
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="net5.0">
        <dependency id="Crc32.NET" version="1.2.0" />
        <dependency id="BouncyCastle.NetCore" version="1.8.10" />
        <dependency id="BouncyCastle.NetCoreSdk" version="1.9.3.1" />
        <dependency id="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" version="6.0.0" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
    
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="SkyBridgeAPI_Software_License_Agreement.txt" target="" />
    <file src="lib\net5.0\FrontEdge.SkyBridgeAPI.dll" target="lib\net5.0" />
  </files>
</package>
```